# Why does Lean enforce recursive type arguments to appear after non-recursive ones?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, recursive-datastructures, induction, lean

The following definition is rejected by Lean:

```
inductive natlist
| nil : natlist
| cons: natlist → ℕ → natlist
```

with the error message ***"arg #2 of 'natlist.cons' is not recursive, but it occurs after recursive arguments***"

And the following definition is accepted, as expected:

```
inductive natlist
| nil : natlist
| cons: ℕ → natlist → natlist
```

What is the reason Lean enforces this order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lean's implementation of inductive types is based on the "Inductive families" paper by P. Dybjer (1994):

> Backhouse [Bac88] and Coquand and Paulin [COP90] allowed the inessential generalisation where recursive premises may precede non-recursive ones. I prefer to put all non-recursive premises before the recursive ones, since the former cannot depend on the latter here (but the situation changes in [Dyb92]). This restriction simplifies the presentation of the scheme and emphasises the relationship with the well-orderings.

Note that a recent [commit](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/commit/1db1f8b229802b916a2287711bac0ef226022e40) removes this restriction and your first definition works now.

Comment: I see your point. However, some people like to define the node part of binary trees like so: `| node : bintree A -> A -> bintree A -> bintree A` :)